# facebook oauth authentication with PHP + Yii doesn't return “code” parameter in response

Tags: php, facebook, authentication, yii

I am using facebook oauth authentication with PHP + Yii.It was working perfectly till last month.But suddenly it doesn't return “code” parameter in response when we do callback request.What could be the reason? Has facebook updated its authentication API recently?

Comment: Just as a starter,have a look at their blog http://developers.facebook.com/blog/ then you can see what they change and what's on their roadmap

Comment: I changed callback URL from 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id='CLIENT_ID'&return_session=true&scope=manage_pages,offline_access,create_event,publish_stream,read_insights,read_mailbox,read_requests,sms,user_photos,read_stream,email,user_checkins' TO 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_URL&scope=read_stream&response_type=code' AND returned response code for me.

Answer (score 0):

I changed callback URL from 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id='CLIENT_ID'&return_session=true&scope=manage_pages,offline_access,create_event,publish_stream,read_insights,read_mailbox,read_requests,sms,user_photos,read_stream,email,user_checkins' TO 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_URL&scope=read_stream&response_type=code' AND returned response code for me.